# Android Test Module rename went wrong

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I wanted to rename de 'test' module folder to 'unitTest' but since them impossible to run my tests on Intelij (on my CI they work).

I tried to invalidate cache, restore default settings on IDE, or rename module.

On project view :

[image: Project View]

On Settings Module view, (I don't know why I have 2 modules, tried to delete but they came back at new reload) :
[image: Settings view]

Here my gradle file with Source Sets :

```java
sourceSets {
            // Adds exported schema location as test app assets.
            debug.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
            customDebugType.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
            androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/src/androidTest".toString())
            test.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/src/test".toString())

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a place where unit tests are in the build.gradle for Modile:app

```
android { 
    sourceSets{
        test {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src/unitTest']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with my gradle content